# Speed up result set mapping

Tags: java, mysql

I am querying a MYSQL database using a prepared statement and result set. When i run the query on MYSQL workbench it is supper fast at returning the results however when it comes to mapping the results to a POJO it takes just over 6 seconds to map the results and return the response to the browser. on 1 query I have 1460 records which are being mapped to a POJO with 17 variable and it take 6 second from making the request to returning a response. can anyone help me try to decrease the return time.

Comment: What did you tried? add code

Comment: It's the query that takes the time, not the mapping.

Comment: No the query completes in under a second

Answer (score 0):

Are you running the query separately for each record, or do you have one query, and fetching the result set after that in a loop? The roundtrip between Java and a DB may be in the magnitude of 0,01 sec, so if you are switching many times between Java and the DB, then it may take some time. Still, I suppose this is not the case, and the slowness is rather caused by the POJO building logic. First add logging statements to your code with time stamps, and see where the time is spent.